# Backbone example, Nodecelarr

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

In nodecelar backbone nodejs sample, i have code :

```
  exports.findById = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Retrieving wine: ' + id);
  db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
        res.send(item);
    });
   });
  };
```

I have error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined.

Can you help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined.

The error says that you're trying to call `findOne` on an undefined variable.

```
db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne(...);
});
```

You call the function on `collection`, so collection must be undefined at that point. My guess is that the db call failed and the `err` is not null.

## The solution

You should handle the error by letting express handle it, or by returning an error message yourself.

```
// use the "next" callback
exports.findById = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Retrieving wine: ' + id);
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        // let express handle the error for you
        if (err) return next(err);
        // or
        if (err) res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' });
        else {
            collection.findOne({ '_id': new BSON.ObjectID(id) }, function(err, item) {
                res.send(item);
            });
        }
    });
};
```